# whots HashMap<String, Object>() in this method

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

First of all sorry for my English :)
I'm new in java and need to set up connection to SQL and create methods for queries, update and so
i found here some nice code about that but cant understand some parts.....

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
                    String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                    Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                    row.put(name, value);
                }
                results.add(row);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        close(rs);
    }
    return results;
}
```

now I suppose that "map" is name of method?

so what is `List < Map < String, Object >>`? i see in second row its some array list but what is meaning of Map, String, Object and bracket?

and whats `HashMap < String, Object > ()` and why its used here?

Comment: This is not php, retagging to java ...

Comment: Tnx guys, all this have much more sense now for me but still 1 question is unanswer, whan i asked is "map" name of method i mean on map after 'List<Map<String, Object>>'

Answer (score 4):

`Map` is an interface that allows you to specify the type of keys in the Map (`String`) and the values those keys match up to (`Object`). `List` is the interface that `ArrayList` implements, so is very similar to `List`. `HashMap` is to `Map` as `ArrayList` is to `List`, so basically a `HashMap` is an implementation of a map. The List allows you to keep track of a series of key/value pairs that `Map` defines for you. For example, String `key` may be matched to an object called `value`, which is where you specified this. More documentation can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to relate directly to the question:

in the second row a variable is being defined, and `List<Map<String, Object>>` is its type. `List<>` type has one generic argument - telling what type of objects are in the list. So this will be a list of map objects, list of `Map<String, Object>` objects to be precise. What does `Map<String, Object>` mean? Its a map with keys of type String, and values of Object type. So, to put this all together: the results variable is a list of maps, each having strings mapped to objects. However, I feel that you just need to calm down and study Java/programming principles from the beginning with a bit more attention :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several topics covered in this code that you seem to know nothing about, so I'm providing links to the relevant sections on the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial).

- [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/): A means of specifying generic arguments to classes, similar to C++ templates.
- [Java Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/): A way of collecting multiple objects in a single object.

If you find the tutorial pages incomprehensible, you may want to fill in the very large blank spots in your java knowledge, with the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial).